# Binding the List items to this.state

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a Recact component defined as:

`export default class App extends React.Component<AppProps, Items>`

The `Items` class is defined as:

`export default class Items extends Array<Item>`

and the `Item` is just a class with a bunch of properties.

If in `render()` I bind a list to my `Items` object directly ie.

`<List items={myItems} onRenderCell={this._onRenderCell} />`

the list is displayed correctly, however if I `this.setState(myItems)` and then try to get the list binded to the state:

`<List items={this.state} onRenderCell={this._onRenderCell} />`

I get the compile-time error:

> > Type 'Readonly' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': [Symbol.iterator], [Symbol.unscopables]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you mean to put `this.state.myItems`?

Comment: no - my state is the items `React.Component<AppProps, Items>`

Comment: If it's not too much trouble, do you mind showing the component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easy solution to this... I created a new type:

```
type ItemsState = {
    items: Items
}
```

then changed my component to use that as a state instead: `export default class App extends React.Component<AppProps, ItemsState>`

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to point out that React's patterns discourage inheritance and prefer [composition](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)

Moreover you are extending an Array while React expect an Object.

Another misconception is "bind a function to the state". You are binding *this* context, not to variables.

Finally, state must be serializable and you should put in it only objects and arrays or primitives.

Try to refactor your components following this guidelines or post complete code for a more comprehensive solution.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Not sure where I am using `inheritance`...? Also an Array is an object - is it not? Also not sure where i am binding functions to the state either.

Comment: export default class Items extends Array<Item> -> you are extending an Array. Yes, in javascript also array are object but as array's index is not tightly coupled to its values state becomes unpredictable.

Comment: That inheritance is not part of the React component model I am creating... it is a data class - i don't think the guideline you referring to, applies here. Thanks for your input though.